# Is LC_ALL=C destructive?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, bash-scripting, text-editing

I have a reasonably large (~15GB) set of text files. These files are essentially simple databases that contain credentials, and the credentials in them often fall outside of the 128-character ASCII range (accented characters and the like).

When I try to sort some of these files with:

`sort -u input.txt -o output.txt`

...I get the following error:

```
sort: string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
```

I've read a lot about how using `LC_ALL=C` can speed up commands that deal with characters, like `sort` and `grep`, including [Stephane Chazelas' brilliant answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/216754) on the topic, but I'm worried specifically about the implications of using it on my dataset.

**Is running `LC_ALL=C sort -u` on these files likely to strip them of any non-ASCII characters?**

**If it is**, then what I can do instead to fix/remove all "*invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide characters*" from these files, allowing me to sort them without using `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: How are you invoking `sort`?

Comment: @DanielB `sort -u <file>`

Comment: what is the coding of the file ? what is your LC_ALL ?

Comment: `sort -u <file>` (from your comment) only reads the file specified as input, it doesn't modify it ([this can be different with `-o`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29698/108618)). Therefore I think the strict answer to the bold question is "no". But if by "to strip them" you mean "to strip *their content* as it passes through `sort`", then it's a different question. For now I think the answer is still no, but I need to do more research and to educate myself before I write a decent answer (if ever).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski My bad, I forgot to include the -o option.

Comment: Well, `sort -u input.txt -o input.txt` would change `input.txt` in general, but `sort -u input.txt -o output.txt` will not.

Comment: @matzeri Of the files I have the `file` command shows 6 of them as being non-ASCII and the rest as ASCII. However, this doesn't seem to be meaningful as sort fails even on the files classified as ASCII, and in my experience weird results with `file` aren't that rare. My locale is `en_GB.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL` is set to nothing, which I believe is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is running LC_ALL=C sort -u on these files likely to strip them of any non-ASCII characters?

Not in this case, no – `sort` will just directly work on the byte values instead of trying to convert them to characters.

However, the same does not necessarily apply to other tools. Programs written in C (the language) are the most likely to behave this way. Programs written in languages with strong byte-vs-char distinction, such as in Python 3, should outright refuse to accept input that doesn't conform to the charset. And I can certainly imagine poorly-written programs which ignore the errors and output a � or a `?` instead.

> If it is, then what I can do instead to fix/remove all "invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide characters" from these files, allowing me to sort them without using LC_ALL=C?

Ensure that they're all using the same file encoding (preferably UTF-8), and that your locale is using the same encoding. The error should never occur for a valid UTF-8 file no matter how large it is.

Comment: Great answer, answered both of my questions, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because I ended up needing to pipe my files through a lot of different Bash tools like `sort`, `grep`, `awk`, `wc` and `tr`, I decided it was safer to go for the "proper solution" indicated in the accepted answer; converting them all to UTF-8 first. This ended up being a little harder than expected, not least because it took me a while to realise that `file` isn't reliable at determining whether a file is ASCII or UTF-8 (because it doesn't check the whole of the file), so I'm putting this answer up here for posterity.

To definitively determine what encoding your files are in, first make sure the `uchardet` package is installed via the Cygwin Installer or [apt-cyg](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg), then run:

```
uchardet *.txt
```

Or if you're not on Cygwin:

```
chardet *.txt
```

Move all of the files that `chardet` lists as `ASCII` to a folder of their own, and run the following `for` loop in that folder:

```
for i in *.txt; do iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8 "$i" >> "${i%.txt}_utf.txt"; done;
```

It will loop through all `.txt` files in a folder and create UTF-8 versions of them with the `utf` suffix added.

Running `uchardet *.txt` again may still show some files as being `ASCII`. This happens because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, and [simply means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36030982/1191147) that those files don't contain characters outside the ASCII range of 128 bits.

You should now be able to run `sort` without needing to use `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: Thank you for the update, it is informative. Fwiw, if using `LC_ALL=C sort` is good enough (if your file mostly starts with ascii informations), it would be much faster than an itf-8 sorting, but if you handle a mix of ascii and non-ascii, utf-8 is the way to go (http://utf8everywhere.org/ would agree ^^)